# Incoming call is not registered on iPhone if iPhone turns of before I pick up

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

The situation:

1. iPhone is low on battery
2. I receive incoming call
3. I try to pick up and phone turns of during that moment

In this situation incoming phone number is not registered on the recent call list.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Charge your phone more often. It obviously isn't getting time to log the call details.

Comment: Well it could be ringing for 5-15sec, but only when I pickup it turns off. Probably, because it draws more current at that point. So technically it has enough current and time to register a call before that, but I was wondering if there is something in the settings to get that working. I don't remember having this problem a year back, it's either related to iOS update or a change of mobile operator.